# Google search that returns a single answer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, search-engine

I want to know how I can implement a Google search in my C# application that returns one answer. For example, when you search for queries like "where is the capital of Spain", google returns a single answer "Madrid" on top of the search results. I want to implement exactly the same thing in my application that returns that single answer. I have read a little about the Google search introduced [here](http://googledotnet.codeplex.com/) APIs but I'm not sure if that does what I want. I think that returns a list of answers.

I have no idea how to do that and your help will be greatly appreciated (even if you can tell me what keywords I should search for that is fine too).

Comment: That API does exactly what you want it to do - and more. It all depends on how you use it. The answer of 'how to use it' is in that exact API's documentation.

Comment: Just as a word of caution (although I'm sure you've thought of this) but when we search, we're not always guaranteed to receive a single answer... What happens then? What if the question was What is Spain's most popular dish... Paella, Tapas, something not for tourists?

Comment: @DaveRook Good Point, Dave.

Comment: @DaveRook I know that but I'm now just interest in searches that return only one answer :)

Comment: @SemiDemented but isn't returning a set of answers instead of a single answer? The documentation of the API I have referred to is empty. Could you please explain a little bit more how I can do this?